# create QApplication or how to const cast in cppfront

Tags: c++, qt, cppfront

I am playing with `cppfront` (https://github.com/hsutter/cppfront), a possible C++ successor, in combination with Qt. I am trying to replicate the simplest possible widget application showing just an empty widget.

In `C++` (aka `cpp1`) it would be like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

In `cppfront` (aka `cpp2`) I am trying this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

main: (args) -> int =
{
    app := QApplication(args.argc, args.argv);
    w := QWidget();
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I build it first with `cppfront` and then with MSVC. It results in errors like `error: C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'QApplication'`. After more trial and error I found out that the problem is that `args.argv` is `char const* const*` while `QApplication` expects `char**` as the second argument. Just to prove this I tried this:

```
main: (args) -> int =
{
    app := QApplication(args.argc, nullptr);
    ...
```

Then the constructor types match well and the program builds and runs fine. Of course it is not correct because it does not pass the arguments. So I tried this:

```
main: (args) -> int =
{
    app := QApplication(args.argc, std::const_cast<char**>(args.argv));
    ...
```

But then `cppfront` complains: `error: 'const_cast' is not supported in Cpp2 - the current C++ best practice is to never cast away const, and that is const_cast's only effective use`. I fully understand this is for memory safety reasons to prevent possible programming errors.

**So my question is: has anyone any simple solution to instantiate a `QApplication` with passing arguments correctly in vanilla `cppfront`?**

PS: I am using `qmake` build with `pro` file:

```
QT = core gui widgets

CONFIG += c++20

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

OTHER_FILES += \
        main.cpp2

INCLUDEPATH += C:\cppfront\include
```

of course you would need to change the `cppfront` include path to match your paths. I am compiling `cpp2` to `cpp` manually with just `cppfront main.cpp` in the command line. So no fancy pre-build steps in qmake yet because I am still just experimenting... What is important in this file is `c++20` flag and that include path. I am using `Qt6.5.2`.

Answer (score 1):

VERSION 1 (not working):

So after a few more trials and errors (you know, there is still no official documentation to `cppfront` available at the moment of writing this) I found this possibility:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

main: (args) -> int =
{
    app := QApplication(args.argc, args.argv as **char); // note the position of **, that's a gotcha for for someone coming from C/C++
    w := QWidget();
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

It builds with `cppfront` with MSVC and runs well. But it does not compile with clang. It shows error `error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'program_violates_type_safety_guarantee<char **, const char *const *>' "No safe 'as' cast available - please check your cast"`

VERSION 2 (working as of 2023-08-16):

I posted query to project page https://github.com/hsutter/cppfront/issues/592 and the author reacted and changed `args.argv` member to `char**`. So the original code `app := QApplication(args.argc, args.argv);` now should work fine. Btw. `args.argv` remains for compatibility with C++. The new and safer way of working with arg is the fact that `args` inherits from `std::vector<std::string_view>` which provides more modern and safer way of working with args. This should be recommended to be used in **cppfront** code.

PS: Please note that **cppfront** project is still evolving and is just an experiment. Many things can change yet. Let's see how well it work together with Qt framework.